# Using OLTP and OLAP in tandem for event processing

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

We're building an API where users can keep calling and sending events to, the events are associated with a particular entity in their respective systems. We expect to be high amount of point-writes (the events), with two kinds of querying patterns:

1. Point reads to get the latest status of a particular entity.
2. Analytical queries that may aggregate and show how entities changed / altered over time.

When building designing this, I was thinking of doing this all in AWS Redshift since it has transactions, and is meant for analytical queries, however that seems like I'm mixing OLTP and OLAP use-cases together.

Another pattern I could go with is to have an OLTP Postgres table (in RDS or Aurora) that keeps the latest status of all the entities, and then stream the events to Redshift and have an almost mirroring setup there. It felt a bit funny to me, however, that we need to mirror the two. It also means that if the transaction fails on the main OLTP table, I may not want to stream the event to Redshift.

We expect the amount of data right now to be quite small, but it may grow with time as we get more clients to use the APIs.

What patterns are common here? Which of the above options is sensible?